# What can be causing Html.ValidateFor() method to produce a compile error?

Tags: linq, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, client-side-validation

I have view with the following which works:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "required_field_light" }) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName) %>
```

However, if I change the ValidationMessageFor() to a ValidateFor() like this:

```
<%= Html.ValidateFor(m => m.FirstName) %>
```

I get this compile error:

```
"The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(char)' has some invalid arguments"
"Argument '1': cannot convert from 'void' to 'char'"
```

I assume I am missing something somewhere but I cannot figure out what it is.  Has anyone else encountered this problem and found a solution, or does somebody have an idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since ValidateFor() returns void, call it like so:

```
<% Html.ValidateFor(m => m.FirstName); %>
```

(Note no equal sign; addition of semicolon.)

Answer (score 6):

For those of you using Razor, you can do the same with

```
@{ Html.ValidateFor(x => x.FirstName); }
```

instead of the usual

```
@Html.ValidateFor(x => x.FirstName)
```

Again, as was mentioned by Levi, because a `ValidateFor` returns `void`, not `MvcHtmlString` like most `Html.` methods. And on that note, having no clue about what you're doing, if you're trying to use `Html.ValidateFor` I'd bet that you actually want to use:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName)
```

Comment: Your last code snippet, I think you mean @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName)